# Truncate option text for selected option and UNtruncate when not selected

Tags: jquery, select, truncate

I wrote a function to truncate select options with text longer than X chars. I need to truncate only the selected option and UNtruncate all options when not selected.

What's happening is they remain shortened forever in the list even when not selected. Also, is there a more concise way of writing this whole block?

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/kirkbross/pcb0a3Lg/9/

```
var namesList = ['johnathan', 'tim', 'greggory', 'ashton', 'elizabeth'];

$(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var name = namesList[i];
        $('#names').append('<option>' + name + '</option>');
    }
    var selected_option = $('#names').find('option:selected').val();
    var truncated = truncate(selected_option);
    $('option:selected').text(truncated.new);

    $('#names').change(function(){
       var selected_option = $(this).find('option:selected').val();
       var truncated = truncate(selected_option);
        $('option:selected').text(truncated.new);
    });

});

function truncate(selected_option) {
    var nameLength = selected_option.length
    if (nameLength > 4) {
        selected_option = selected_option.substr(0, 4) + '...';
    }
    return {new: selected_option}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:  Create a clone of the select element, which contains the truncated options, positioned absolutely on top of the select.

When hovering, show the original select instead of the clone.

When you change the select, change it in the clone as well.

```js
$(function() {
  var namesList = ['johnathan', 'tim', 'greggory', 'ashton', 'elizabeth'];
    
  //append all at once:
  $('#names').append('<option>'+namesList.join('</option><option>')+'</option>');
    
  $('#names option').each(function() {
    var txt = $(this).text();
    if(txt.length > 4) txt= txt.substr(0,4)+'…';  //use an ellipsis instead of 3 dots
    $('#clone').append('<option>'+txt+'</option>');
  });

  $('#names').change(function() {
    $('#clone')[0].selectedIndex= this.selectedIndex;
  });
});
```

```css
#clone, #names {
  width: 90px;
}

#clone {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#names {
  position: relative;
}

div:hover #names {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="clone"></select>
  <select id="names"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This definitely works, but feels a little too "brute force" if that makes any sense. I feel like there must be a way to store the original values and recall them when not selected.

Comment: I think it would be difficult to create a cross-browser solution that does what you want.